# ¿Por qué la página se muestra en blanco al recuperar datos desde una base de datos?

Tags: php

Por alguna razón que desconozco la pág me queda en blanco.

Explico un poco el contexto del código: este código me debería de mostrar una tabla con la información extraída de la base de datos. Cuando la BD está vacía la página funciona correctamente, pero cuando agrego información a la base de datos la página queda completamente en blanco.

Estuve revisando el código línea por línea, pero no encuentro el porqué.

```
<?php 
 error_reporting(0);
 session_start();
 include("conexion.php");
 include("encabezado.php");
 
 // INICIO MOSTRAR PRODUCTOS
 echo'<b>Lista de Productos</b><br><br>';
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM `producto`";
 $query = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql);
 $num = mysqli_num_rows($query);
 
 if($num){
     echo '<table cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">';
     $a = 1; $b = 1;
     
     while($row = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql)){
         $id[$a][$b] = $row['id_producto'];
         $nombre[$a][$b] = $row['nombre_producto'];
         $precio[$a][$b] = $row['precio'];
         $existencia[$a][$b] = $row['existencia'];
         $descripcion[$a][$b] = $row['descripcion'];
         $archivo[$a][$b] = $row['nombre_archivo']; 
         
         if($b == 4){
             $a++;
             $b=1;
             }
             $b++;
         }
         if($num >= 3){
             $condicion = 3;
             }else{
                 $condicion = $num;
                 }
         $c = 1; $d = 1;
         
     for($c = 0; $c <= $a; $c++){
         echo"<tr>";
             for($d = 0; $d <= $condicion; $d++){
                 echo'<td><b>Nombre:</b>'.$nombre[$c][$d].'<br><br>
                          <b>Precio:</b>'.$precio[$c][$d].'<br><br>
                          <b>Existencia:</b>'.$existencia[$c][$d].'Unidad(es)<br><br>
                          <b>Descripci&oacute;n:</b>'.$descripcion[$c][$d].'<br><br>
                          <b>Imagen:</b><br>
                          <img src="'.$archivo[$c][$d].'" width="75" height="75"><br><a href="validar.php?id_producto='.$id[$c][$d].'">Agregar al Carrrito</a>
                          </td>';
                 }
             echo"</tr>";
         }
         echo'</table>';
     }
     else{
         echo"No Existen productos Cargados en el Sistema";
         }
 if($_SESSION['carrito']){echo'<br><br><a href="carrito.php">Ver Carrito</a>';}
 if($_SESSION['tipo_usuario'] == "Administrador"){echo'<br><br><a href="menu.php">Men&uacute;</a>';}
 if($_SESSION['activo']){echo'<br><br><a href="salir.php">Salir</a>';}
 echo'<br><br><a href="login.php">Ingresar al sistema</a>';
 include("pie.php");?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo habilitar la visualización de errores `display_errors` en tu `php.ini` para que te alerte sobre los errores que presentas. Esto es porque solo ejecutas la consulta pero no la recorres correctamente en el `while`, necesitas agregar `mysqli_fetch_assoc($query).`

Answer (score 0):

Cuando haces una llamada a mysqli_query(), te devolverá false si se produjo algún error o un conjunto de filas de la tabla consultada, en tu ejemplo a este resultado le llamas $query.
Ahora tienes que ir sacando cada valor desde $query, eso se hace con **mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)**.

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
```

Lo que tu hacías era repetir la consulta una y otra vez.